# What happen when we use wrong notify()?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

If other threads waiting different condition, we should call notifyAll(), so every other thread has a chance to gain the execution.

But we make a mistake, we suppose all thread waiting for the same condition, we call notify(), let JVM select one thread, but the selected thread cannot run, because the condition still cannot satisfy, then what will happen?

all thread stop running? or the JVM continue to choose another thread to wake up, just like notifyALL() ?

Comment: `but the selected thread cannot run, because the condition still cannot satisfy` please elaborate?

Comment: thread a: while(a>0), thread b: while(b>0), thread c: while(c>0)...

Comment: `notify` wakes up a thread that has called `wait` on that object. There's  nothing to satisfy here.

Comment: @lovespring well, in that case the thread will most likely just `wait` again and _maybe_ wake some other thread up. Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM cannot continue to choose another thread to wake up because the decision to re-enter `wait` happens at a higher level of logic, beyond the reach of thread scheduler's "horizon". So yes, in your described scenario all the threads will keep on waiting.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should have a `deadlock` because all the threads will be stuck in waiting.

Answer (score 0):

```
thread a: while(a>0), thread b: while(b>0), thread c: while(c>0)
```

That is your code logic that is flawed. And yes it will lead to `deadlock`. Since you have while thread will continue to eat up your CPU and since it holds the lock no other thread can acquire it.

> all thread stop running? or the JVM continue to choose another thread to wake up, just like notifyALL() ?

Thread which will get the lock over critical region will go in infinite loop. All other thread will keep waiting. no JVM will not notify other threads as long as some thread is holding the lock.

Answer (score 0):

All of the threads that are wait()ing for the same monitor should be waiting in a loop for the same condition to become true.  The thread that notify()s the monitor should only do so after *making* the condition true.  If you follow those rules, then at least one thread will wake up and be able to make progress.

E.g.;

```
final Object lock = new Object();
final AtomicBoolean timeToGo = new AtomicBoolean(false);

Runnable waiter = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            while (! timeToGo.get()) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            System.out.println("Hello!");
            timeToGo.set(false);
        }
    }
};

Runnable notifier = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            timeToGo.set(true);
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
};
```

If five threads are hanging in the wait() method of waiter.run(), and one thread calls notifier.run(), then exactly one of the five will print "Hello!" and exit.  The others will continue to wait for the next notifier.run() call.

If you want all of the threads to print hello when notifier.run() is called, then change the lock.notify() call to lock.notifyAll(), and remove the line from waiter.run() that sets the flag back to false.